# How to access store from componentDidMount()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is a possible duplicate of

[How to access redux-store from within react's componentDIdMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982033/how-to-access-redux-store-from-within-reacts-componentdidmount)

I am finding that example to be confusing and more complicated than my implementation, so I'm going to risk asking again with a simpler code.

I need to access my redux store from `componentDidMount()`. The following code renders the `<h3>` component but `console.log()`'s a `null` value:

```
class FinishedPaying extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.paymentID);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.paymentID}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    paymentID: state.paymentID
  };
};

const mapActionsToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      updatePaymentID: updatePaymentID
    },
    dispatch
  );
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapActionsToProps
)(FinishedPaying);
```

reducer code:

```
import { UPDATE_PAYMENTID } from "../actions/paymentID-actions";

export default function paymentIDReducer(state = "", { type, payload }) {
  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_PAYMENTID:
      return payload.paymentID;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

actions code:

```
export const UPDATE_PAYMENTID = "paymentID:updatePaymentID";

export function updatePaymentID(newPaymentID) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_PAYMENTID,
    payload: {
      paymentID: newPaymentID
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: can you also share the reducer code? you're probably missing something in here `paymentID: state.paymentID`

Comment: Thanks for helping! Question though..if I have something wrong in the reducer code, why is it correctly rendering the <h3> element?

Comment: oh this is the only store you have? I usually have `state.name_of_the_store.name_of_the_property`, thats why I though the error could be there.

When is the `updatePaymentID` function called? Can you also put a console.log on the render and check if in the first render the paymentId is null?

Comment: What triggers the rendering of `FinishedPaying`? I suspect that `paymentID` is starting as null and then being updated resulting in a re-rendering. If you do a `console.log` in the render I suspect you'll see it once as null (in sync with the mount) and then again with the `paymentID` specified.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Cogswell, you nailed it!

I was updating the store after a re-direct, switched it to before the re-direct and it is now working.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, delete the question or write a high-quality answer (see [answer]).

Comment: I'll rephrase my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `componentDidMount` shows one value (via console.log) and a different value is being rendered, one likely explanation is that the component is being re-rendered immediately after mount (e.g. an initial rendering with a null value and then a redux action is dispatched immediately after the initial rendering that sets the value). You can easily see whether or not this is the case by doing a `console.log` from the `render` method. I would expect that you will see two logs from the `render` method -- one in sync with `componentDidMount` and then another with the value you see rendered.

In order to have the appropriate value in `componentDidMount` you will need to change the order of events such that the component isn't rendered until after the state has been updated or re-organize the logic in `componentDidMount` to leverage other/additional lifecycle methods to recognize when the value changes and deal with it appropriately.